# sympy: show all symbolic variables that have been substituted in an expression

Tags: python, sympy

Is it possible to reveal all symbolic variables that are involved in a sympy expression?

Here is some sample code that could be potentially quite confusing:

```py
from sympy import *
from sympy.stats import Normal, sample, variance

sigma_eps = symbols('sigma_eps')
eps = Normal("eps", 0, sigma_eps)

sigma_any = eps + 1
sigma_1 = (eps+1).subs({sigma_eps:1})
sigma_10 = (eps+1).subs({sigma_eps:10})
```

If you print `sigma_any, sigma_1` or `sigma_10` they all look the same. They will all tell you that their value is `eps + 1`. But actually, the values are completely different distributions.

Is it possible to reveal what random variables have been used and already substituted for an expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a general rule (not always followed) that the string form of an expression should be copy and pastable to recreate the object. This case is an exception and an issue at https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues could be opened.

You can tell they are not the same if you inspect the srepr` forms:

```
>>> srepr(sigma_1)==srepr(sigma_10)
False
```

Also, `free_symbols` does not show what you want, but the difference between atoms before and after substituion will reveal what has been changed:

```
>>> sigma_any.free_symbols
{eps}
>>> sigma_any.atoms()
{0, 1, eps, sigma_eps}
>>> sigma_1.atoms()
{0, 1, eps}
```

Note that `sigma_eps` is missing in the last output.